# SQL - pull data for date range based on a start date

Tags: sql, datetime, sum, left-join, amazon-redshift

I have the below SQL query, which pulls account revenues for the past 3 months, along with each account's service start date (I'm using Amazon Redshift via SQL Workbench)

```
select distinct r.account_id, r.account_name, s.start_date
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN r.datekey between '20200601' and '20200630' THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) AS "June 2020" 
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN r.datekey between '20200701' and '20200731' THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) AS "July 2020"
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN r.datekey between '20200801' and '20200831' THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) AS "August 2020"  
from revenues r
join start_dates s on r.account_id = s.account_id
group by r.account_id, r.account_name, s.start_date;
```

How can modify the above query to pull revenues for the 3 months after each client's start date, keeping in mind this 3-month range will be different for each client? I've tried using DATEPART and DATEADD but I haven't found a solution using those statements.

Comment: I would use DATEDIFF and make sure the number is <=90

Answer (score 1):

You can change the join conditions to filter the revenues of each `account_id` on the 3 months that follow it `start_date`, and then use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    s.account_id,
    sum(case when r.datekey < dateadd(month, 1, s.start_date) then revenue else 0 end) as month1,
    sum(case when r.datekey >= dateadd(month, 1, s.start_date) and r.datekey < dateadd(month, 2, s.start_date) then revenue else 0 end) as month2,
    sum(case when r.datekey >= dateadd(month, 2, s.start_date) then revenue else 0 end) as month3
from start_dates s
left join revenues r
    on  r.account_id = s.account_id
    and r.datekey >= s.start_date
    and r.datekey <  dateadd(month, 3, s.start_date)
group by s.account_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, use DATEDIFF with start_date and GETDATE()

```
select distinct r.account_id, r.account_name, s.start_date
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN r.datekey between '20200601' and '20200630' THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) AS "June 2020" 
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN r.datekey between '20200701' and '20200731' THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) AS "July 2020"
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN r.datekey between '20200801' and '20200831' THEN revenue ELSE 0 END) AS "August 2020"  
from revenues r
join start_dates s on r.account_id = s.account_id
WHERE DATEDIFF(s.start_date, GETDATE())<=90
group by r.account_id, r.account_name, s.start_date;
```